# What is the best practice when using HTTP methods which include (GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE) regarding how to pass parameters/data to the server?

Tags: api, rest, http, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

From my experience, this is what I understand at the moment.

1. Get, delete: we should use query string(filter, sorting...), target-uri-identifier(api/users/1) to pass the data to server, avoid to pass the data in the body of request
2. Post, put, patch: we should send data in the body of the request or
   use target-uri-identifier for put, patch, and avoid using query string in these three methods

Please correct me if I am wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to always avoid passing data in the body of a get request. There may be certain cases where just query params are not enough. You might have to pass complex JSON objects to the API. In those cases, it makes sense to send the data in a payload, i.e in the body of a get request.
Checkout this post for more information: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/should-you-send-payload-http-get-request-arpit-bhayani/?trk=articles_directory